# jsxgraph svg width and height is setting to zero

Tags: jsxgraph

I recently encountered an issue where the JSXGraph svg element has width and height set as zero.
It happens when I load the jsxgraph content in iframe. This issue occurs randomly.
Any idea what could be the reason?

I'm attaching a screenshot of the page when this issue occurred.
Here the 'box' element has the width and height set by css file as 500x500. 
I tried setting the 'box' dimension inline but it didn't help. 
Somehow the svg element created by jsxgraph setting the height and width as 0,0.

[image: page screenshot in error scenario]

Comment: This is indeed strange. Does it also happen if you execute all the JSXGraph code with a small time delay? I mean, if you put the JSXGraph code in a function and call that function with - say - setTimeout(callJSXGraph, 100)?

Comment: No, it does not. It renders perfectly even for setting timeouts. In error scenario, 
One more observation I see is with clientHeight and clientWidth values of box element. They appear 0 before rendering JSXGraph. However, at the same time , jquery $(box).width() gives 500.